# Word that describes someone who believes all their actions are justified.

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is a word for someone who believes all their actions are justified. Like they believe their ideology is the best one there even if it is against society set morals.

Comment: How about deluded?

Answer (score 0):

Self-righteous, or if that’s two words, sanctimonious.  But keep in mind that societal morals have included witch burning and other such sanctimonious offenses.

Comment: Given at the linked thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of possibilities, including

> - dogmatic
> - doctrinaire
> - intransigent
> - cocksure
> - unbending
> - uncompromising
> - narrow-minded
> - fanatical
> - pertinacious
> - adamant
> - unyielding
> - unswerving

Most of the above words I obtained from [Word Hippo](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/tenacious.html), a great site for synonyms and antonyms.